# Is it possible to set a shortcut for MySQL CLI to "delete word through Ctrl+W"?

Tags: mysql

Current default behavior is that MySQL CLI deletes whole line.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, MySQL version 8.0

Comment: [it looks like it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#mysql-input-editing). Feel free to add an answer after you test it.

Comment: @danblack I created `.editrc` file in my home directory and added this line `bind "^W" ed-delete-prev-word` but its not working.